# Qt5: How to use qDebug() to log in a file, multi-thread application

Tags: multithreading, qt, logging, thread-safety

I started using Qt5 few days ago. I needed a *logger* for my app and I decided to use `qDebug`, but it seems it has to be "redirected" in order to have the logs in a file.

I used `qInstallMessageHandler` to do that and I wrote my own handler as presented below (inspired from other people here).

It seems it works, but as I am not a guru, I have to ask:
Is it ok to use this in a multi-thread application or not?

Also, if it is ok/safe for using in a *multi-thread* app, can it be improved somehow?

```
void MessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext & context, const QString & msg)
{
    mutex.lock();

    QDateTime dateTime(QDateTime::currentDateTime());

    QString timeStr(dateTime.toString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:zzz"));
    QString contextString(QString("(%1, %2)").arg(context.file).arg(context.line));

    QFile outFile("file.log");
    outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);

    QTextStream stream(&outFile);
    stream << timeStr << " " << contextString << ": " << msg << endl;

    mutex.unlock();
}
```

Comment: Which type has your variable `mutex`?

Comment: static QMutex mutex; // global variable

Comment: For which OS are you developing?

Comment: Is that going to be a server application? How many different threads are you expecting?

Comment: Yes indeed, a server application with about 30 threads (at maximum). - Works well with 4 threads, yet with 30 threads it becomes really sluggish.

Comment: Okay then better go for the logging thread approach of @Nejat's answer

Comment: @Simon: I wish I knew how to do that, but I'm just a beginner. I asked Nejat (see below), but probably he is busy or something. Please, can you help me a little, just to have it started? Thanks in advance! Stanley.

Comment: definitely best question about qt logging anyone could ever ask so neat, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach looks simple and clean. I'd keep it like that.

There is one thing you can improve: Open the file only once at application start and close it when you close the application. Opening a file is an expensive operation.

You can write into the same open file from multiple threads, since your mutex ensures that only one thread writes at the same time.

Comment: Simon, thanks for taking the time and for your advice! I would open the file only once at startup, but (in the very near future) I am planning to change the file name from "file.log" to something like "dd-mm-yyy.log"... I'm sure you know what I mean :) So, it would be somehow impossible to open the log-file at application start... Any idea/workaround for this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @groenhen Are you expecting that the application runs more than one day?

Comment: Yes, it will run non-stop (at least I hope so :)...)

Comment: @groenhen Take one step at a time, dude. If you have everything up and running, you can later add a  function that closes the file, moves it to an archive and opens a new one. Since this function locks the same mutex as log writers do, this can be done without bigger trouble.

Comment: Simon, what will happen if application finish by accident? power of, for example...
the log will be lost, is not it?

Comment: @nat endl probably flushes to disk. But you can flush explicitely after every log line to be super safe.

Answer (score 6):

You can not find anywhere in the Qt documentation that `qDebug` is thread-safe. So it is not safe to call it simultaneously from multiple threads and indeed you would encounter mixed output if you don't use a locking mechanism.

Your locking approach would be better if you use `QMutexLocker` as it is strongly recommended by the Qt documentation:

```
void MessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext & context, const QString & msg)
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    ...
}
```

A second approach is to provide a worker class that has slots for writing the log. You can then have an instance of it in a new thread and call it's slots in message handler using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` with a `Qt::QueuedConnection` connection type. This way each call from each thread would be queued and process in the worker thread and it would probably have a better performance since all the job is done in a separate thread.

Comment: But AFAIK, " QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);" does the same job as mutex.lock() followed by mutex.unlock(), the only difference is that you don't have to worry if/when that function/method has multiple exit/return points. The mutex will be automatically unlocked on exit as locker is an auto variable. Regards, SG.

Comment: BTW: What about "in terms of speed"...? Which one performs faster, mutex lock/unlock() or a QMutexLocker mechanism?

Comment: I am not aware if they differ in terms of speed. But a second approach is to have a worker thread and perform operations there. See the edited answer.

Comment: I would be interested in your "2nd approach", yet since I am just a beginner with Qt (and C++) I am not really able to implement the code/coding... Please can you elaborate ?  I would really like to try this approach!

Comment: if this mutex is only used here, why not using a local static mutex instead of global ?

Answer (score 0):

I saw no reply to your concerns about sluggish, I'm sure by this time you figured something out. You could probably improve performance by reducing the amount of code within the critical region. File operations are slow so try to reduce the amount of time spent doing them. This can include keeping the file open, buffering the log and writing periodically, construct the entry out of the locked region and

```
void MessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext & context, const QString & msg)
{

    QDateTime dateTime(QDateTime::currentDateTime());

    QString timeStr(dateTime.toString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:zzz"));
    QString contextString(QString("(%1, %2)").arg(context.file).arg(context.line));
    QString entryString("%1 %2: %3");
    entryString = entryString.arg(timeStr).arg(contextString).arg(msg);

    QFile outFile("file.log");

    mutex.lock();
    outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append);  
    QTextStream stream(&outFile);  
    stream << entryString << endl;    
    mutex.unlock();
}
```