# Qt Logger framework

Tags: c++, qt, logging

This is possible a duplicate, notheless old questions might be outdated.

I know the basic logging principles of Qt, using `qDebug() << "error"`
and I know that with Qt 5.2 categories where introduced (example found here: https://evileg.com/en/post/154/)
But I do not see that Qt provides a framework ready to use.

I would like to have a file write based logger, thread save, that is compatible with log4net (or log4j). Even if not with the output of log4net it should be stable and proven to work.

I found `log4qt`
https://sourceforge.net/projects/log4qt/ But the source does not even include a make file or anything to make it. Also the code is from 2009 and very likely outdated.

I also found the log4cxx, but that is based on Linux compile tools and I could not find out how to make it using ming32 on windows. Since I dislike to invest hours to even compile a framework I rather not want to use this framework.

Is there anything more modern, up to date for Qt, usable on windows?

Comment: I use https://github.com/dept2/CuteLogger

Comment: Here is my first attempt - about 4 years ago - to use qDebug to log in a file, multi-thread applicatio: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29449237/4731718

Comment: In 2015, I adapted the original Log4Qt v0.3 to compile it with Qt5.4. I am Stanley Groenhen here: https://sourceforge.net/p/log4qt/wiki/0.4%20Features/ ...But I abandoned the project. Log4Qt lacks an important feature: it doesn't provide thread ID in the logs... :(

Comment: I also tried to compile&build log4cxx for mingw32, but with no success. Why don't you set your Qt to use msvc2015-32bit instead of mingw32? Then you should be able to use log4cxx.dll built for msvc2015.